# Upload de múltiplos arquivos usando a mesma requisição?

Tags: javascript, upload, vue.js, quasar, hapijs

Estou usando o VueJS/Quasar Framework para fazer o front-end da minha aplicação e HapiJS para fazer o servidor. E na parte de fazer upload dos anexos estou realizando teste com upload de múltiplos arquivos, e me deparei com o seguinte problema:

**Para cada arquivo o QUploader faz uma requisição para o servidor**([QUploader](http://quasar-framework.org/components/uploader.html) é o componente do Quasar que estou utilizando para selecionar os arquivos e relizar o upload).

Segue código:

Front-end [VueJS](https://vuejs.org/)/[Quasar Framework](http://quasar-framework.org/guide/index.html)

```
<q-uploader multiple :url="url.url" color="light-blue-10" />
```

Componente que utilizo para fazer upload

Servidor HapiJS:

```
server.route({
path: '/upload',
method: 'post',
config: {
    payload: {
        output: 'stream',
        parse: true,
        allow: 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    cors: {
        origin: ['*'],
        additionalHeaders: ['cache-control', 'x-requested-with', 'Accept',
            'Authorization', 'Content-Type', 'f-None-Match', 'Accept-language']
    }
},
handler: function (request, reply) {
    let data = request.payload;
    if (data.file) {
        let name = data.file.hapi.filename;
        let path = __dirname + "/uploads/" + name;
        let file = fs.createWriteStream(path);
        file.on('error', function (err) {
            console.error(err)
        });

        data.file.pipe(file);

        data.file.on('end', function (err) {
            let ret = {
                filename: data.file.hapi.filename,
                headers: data.file.hapi.headers
            };
            return reply.response(JSON.stringify(ret));
        })
    }
}
});
```

Como faço para fazer todos os downloads na mesma requisição??